# What does the "duration in ms" in testng-results.xml of TestNG result represent?

Tags: android, selenium, testng, ui-automation, appium

I am new to Android and iOS automation. I am using Appium for automating the same. I have written my test in TestNG for running an Android App on emulator. My code launches the App on emulator and then uses a username and password to login to the app. I wanted to find the time taken to Login into the App. To be specific the time taken after the **SIGN IN** button is clicked and the home screen appears. Can I use the testNG results.xml file as I see it has :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duration in ms means how long whole method (@BeforeClass, @Test etc.) took. If you want to check login performance this is not a good way because you can have other operations in these methods and TestNG also do some stuff here. It's better to check it explicitly. Something like:

```
final Date startTime = new Date();
clickSignIn();
// wait until/check if home screen is properly displayed
// if it's not done in clickSignIn method (should be)
final Date endTime = new Date();

final long loginTime = endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime(); // in ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that timing the code by `Date()` is extremely imprecise. I would advise another package:

```
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    ----------------------call--your--function--here
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println(duration / 1000000. + " ms.");
```